# Where to place sitemap.xml in playframework 2.1 project

Tags: sitemap, playframework-2.1

Just for a quick question. Where does the sitemap.xml to place in play framework 2.1 project? do we need to configure the route file to the sitemap.xml?

Appreciate your help

thanks,
Best rgsd,
a1ucard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either an Action generates dynamically your `sitemap.xml`, then you have to configure the URL like this:

```
GET   /sitemap.xml    controllers.Application.sitemapGenerator
```

Either you generate your `sitemap.xml` by hand, then put it in the `public` folder of your Play app, and then add an Asset route:

```
GET   /sitemap.xml    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file = "sitemap.xml")
```